Webpack creates extra bundle when a bundle imports a script
I have a bundle that I only import in a users' profile pages named profile.bundle.js
webpack.config.js
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        common: "./src/shared/_Layout.ts",
        profile: "./src/profile/index.ts",
        "profile.editor": "./src/profile/editor.ts"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: "ts-loader",
                exclude: /node_modules/,
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    { loader: "style-loader" },
                    {
                        loader: "css-loader",
                        options: {
                            modules: true
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".js"],
    },
    output: {
        filename: "[name].bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "../wwwroot/js/webpack"),
        clean: true
    },
    optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
            chunks: "all"
        }
    }
};

src/profile/index.ts
console.log("PROFILE INDEX"); // This correctly logs to the console

but when I add an import to the file which I need to register a custom HTML element...
import "../custom-elements/game-card/game-card";

console.log("PROFILE INDEX"); // Does not log

...webpack creates a src_profile_index_ts.bundle.js file in the output folder resulting in the profile.bundle.js not executing at all.
